# Unable to deploy app due to wrong permissions in some files

Tags: openshift

Its been a while since i had to modify an application. Today doing another deploy I got

```
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 1.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping Cron cartridge
remote: CLIENT_RESULT: cron scheduling service is already disabled for gear <<OPENSHIFHASH>>
remote: Stopping PHP 5.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
remote: Stopping PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Operation not permitted - /var/lib/openshift/<<OPENSHIFHASH>>/app-deployments/2016-09-25_11-55-15.153/repo/utils/PkgInfo.pyc
To ssh://<<OPENSHIFHASH>>@<<APP>>.rhcloud.com/~/git/app.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<<OPENSHIFHASH>>@<<APP>>.rhcloud.com/~/git/app.git/'
```

Then I logged in using ssh and I found out that in fact that file `PkgInfo.pyc` is own by `root` when in fact should be owned by the app

like this

```
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>  2929 Sep 25 11:55 HashCache.pyc
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>     0 Sep 25 11:55 __init__.py
-rw-------. 1 root                     root                       101 Oct 23 00:10 __init__.pyc
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>  8991 Sep 25 11:55 MultiPart.py
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>  8051 Sep 25 11:55 MultiPart.pyc
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>   646 Sep 25 11:55 PkgInfo.py
-rw-------. 1 root                     root                       613 Oct 23 00:10 PkgInfo.pyc
-rw-------. 1 <<OPENSHIFHASH>> <<OPENSHIFHASH>>  6607 Sep 25 11:55 Progress.py
```

Why would that file changed the owner? That file was updated on Oct, the 23 but me (as the app) I'm not able to change them to `root`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the same issue though with different cartridges/application architecture so the error log is different. OpenShift help suggested [to file a bug about it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1421295).

My current workaround uses manual deployments:

1. Disable auto deployment with `$ rhc app-configure <YOUR_APP> --no-auto-deploy`
2. `$ git push origin`
3. `$ ssh <YOUR_APP>@<YOUR_APP>.rhcloud.com`
4. `$ gear build`
5. Run `gear start` for all your cartridges - make sure that they run successfully

This is not optimal but hope it helps.